# Mount on the fly compressed filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, compression, fuse

I'm looking for solution for not enough disk space on our server to store backups.

We have virtual server. When we dump data from database to disk it consumes lot of space. But it could be easily compressed by 30-50% using zip. We then move this dumps to backup server. We just need to reduce disk space used by dumps on disk.

I would like to find solution which will allow me to somehow mount temp filesystem to store dump.

I find fusecompress project whichdoes what we need but it seems still experimental and does not have official Debian package, so I am not sure if it is safe choice for production server backups.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use btrfs with this mount option: compress-force=zlib

It's possible then to make filesystem-level RAID to ensure that if one partition/disk fails data is not lost.

Btrfs also offers snapshots so you could possibly make snapshot of given subvolume and then make a backup to the previously snapshotted subvolume, saving space by doing this.

And there is a way to convert exisiting ext4 partition to btrfs.

More about btrfs features: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I should have mentioned this is on virtual server, so we cannot change underlaying filesystem.

Comment: You can use BTRFS on a virtual server - If you don't want to replace / with it, just add a block device for it.